# ZeroMQ Websockets with SSL through CERTBOT

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, zeromq, wss

I have a server-side application that hosts a https secure webpage on port 443, and also needs to host two additional websockets. One of the websockets will be communicating to "workers" I program directly through tcp.(I will deal with adding security to this later and separately). The other websocket needs to be secure and accessible by a client using a browser at wss://mydomain.com. The catch is I am using certbot, and as far as I have read, certbot will only place an ssl certificate on port 443, which is already occupied by my apache2 webserver.

I am creating my websockets in php (no tomcat) with zeromq. I have tried to use proxies on my apache server, for instance:

ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:500

and run my websocket on port 500 but everything I've tried always either does not connect, or returns an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error or a ERR_NETWORK__AUTHENTICATION_INVALID (or some such error saying my ssl certificate is not valid).

I have also tried to extend the certificate to other ports. Nothing is working.

Comment: It turns out I was probably setting up a proxy pass correctly but, I was trying to connect php ZeroMQ sockets server side to browser WebSockets client side. These appear to be incompatible.

Comment: I switched to a nodejs server and socket.io sockets for the browser and all my troubles have flown away. Socket.io automatically proxies all the websockets through the same port at the server. So I don’t expect adding ssl to be too difficult though I haven’t tried it yet. Nodejs seems to be ideally suited for sockets as it seems to be inherently asynchronous. Socket.io sockets can be used as pub/sub sockets but also as any other types of sockets (though nobody seems interested in anything besides pub/sub) and nodejs has a ZeroMQ library.